# chmod(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, file-upload, chmod

this might be a duplicate but dont know the reason why i got this error.. this code is fine when im using another laptop which the php version is 5.6 but when im using a laptop with php version 5.4 i got an error..
here is the code that im using..

```
        public function uploadImg($file, $newname){

            $path = "../valenciamd/captured_images/";
            $fileparts = pathinfo($file["name"]);
            $name =  $newname . $fileparts["extension"];

            if( is_dir($path) === false ){
                mkdir($path);
            }

            $i = 0;
            $parts = pathinfo($name);
            // while (file_exists($path . $name)) {
            //     $i++;
            //     $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
            // }
            $name = $parts["filename"]. "." . $parts["extension"];
            $success = move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],
                $path . $name);

            chmod($path . $name, 0777);

            return $path . $name;
        }
```

`$img = $reg->uploadImg( $_FILES['image'], $patientID.'.');`

Comment: can you confirm that file is really uploaded in the specified path and exist?

Comment: i already check if the file is uploaded but i didn't saw anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your php version is 5.4, maybe it's below 5.2  $path_parts['filename'] is only added since php 5.2 so you will get nothing. This is not an error, just update your php version.

Or if you do not want to update your php version, you can use
`$parts['basename']` instead of `$parts["filename"]. "." . $parts["extension"]`

Answer (score 0):

try to use the recursive directory creation
read the **mkdir** manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

> bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive =
>   false [, resource $context ]]] )